# How to make nginx redirect to a different port

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have the following location block in the nginx.conf file.

```
Location /e-ui/ {
    proxy_pass https://hostname:9000
}
```

I need to know how I can redirect sites in the following manner:

https://abc/e-ui/ should be redirected to https://abc:9000

OR

https://xyz/e-ui/ should be redirected to https://xyz:9000

The server name is changing ( as the code is deployed on many servers ). Is there anyway I can get the server name from the /etc/hosts file if it is already defined there and use it somehow to redirect the sites as mentioned above ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` if you are trying to access a process on the same server?

Comment: Create an individual nginx vhost for each server name maybe?! You need some automation tool to do that like ansible or maybe you can just use a simple bash script that will generated the vhost based on the server name (could be taken from /etc/hosts if that entry actually exists there) How are those servers deployed?!